# Facebook Koala (rails) : fetch a group and its members using a single batch request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.1, koala

I'm new to the facebook graph API, and I can't find a way to achieve this.
All my groups have less than 15 users (splitting requests is not required)

I'm currently using a loop which calls the API for each request, witch is very slow :

```
fb_groups = facebook.get_connections("me","groups?parent=xxxxxxxxxxx")

###### groups parsing and selection

id_members.each do |id|
 User.fb_find(id) # gets the user information using get_object
end
```

Thanks in advance,